# Save custom timestamp column to db after the row has been created

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a table in my db that includes a nullable timestamp column.

```
$table->timestamp('custom_timestamp')->nullable();
```

When the row in the db is created this column will be null. Later when the user does this specific thing I want to update this column with the timestamp when the user did this.

My question: What is the syntax for adding the custom timestamp to this column?

Pseudo code explanation:

```
$myObject->custom_timestamp = *AD THE CURRENT TIME*;
$myObject->save();
```

**EDIT:**
If you downvote a seemingly legit question please explain your concerns in the comments

Comment: In this case better use the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the timestamp like so:

**Carbon**

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$myObject->custom_timestamp = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

**Eloquent**

```
$myObject->custom_timestamp = $myObject->freshTimestampString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Carbon library](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for datetime related issue. Do the following if you want to set the current time of the user's action.

```
$object->custom_timestamp = Carbon::now();
$object->save();
```

Or

```
$object->update(['custom_timestamp' => Carbon::now() ]);
```

To use Carbon in your code, add this line after `<?php`

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

If Carbon is not already in your project add the library by running the following command:

```
$ composer require nesbot/carbon
```

You don't need to use this library just for the task, but I really love this much powerful library and recommend.

Answer (score 2):

use laravel carbon. you can also format the date you want to save. read more here: [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
$now = Carbon::now();
$myObject->custom_timestamp = $now; // 2018-10-16 22:02:28
$myObject->save();
```